# General expression for a higher order derivative

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have expression 
$f(x)=\frac{e^{-a x}}{(b x+1)^2}$. I want to write the $k$th derivative, $f^{(k)}(x)$, in general form as i am looking for the Taylor series expansion. When I checked few first derivative terms, I could not see any patter which helps to write the $k$th one.

$f^{(1)}(x)=-\frac{a e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^2}-\frac{2 b e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^3},
~f^{(2)}(x)=\frac{a^2 e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^2}+\frac{6 b^2 e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^4}+\frac{4 a b e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^3},
~f^{(3)}(x)=-\frac{a^3 e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^2}-\frac{6 a^2 b e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^3}-\frac{24 b^3 e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^5}-\frac{18 a b^2 e^{-a \lambda }}{(b \lambda +1)^4}, ....$

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Are you looking for the $k^{th}$ derivative for any $x$ or for $x=0$ ?

Comment: Actually, it is sufficient to have $x=0$ as I need the Taylor expansion around $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write you the first dozen, you find the pattern
$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
\text{order} & \text{derivative}\\
\hline
 1 & -\frac{e^{-a x} (b x a+a+2 b)}{(b x+1)^3} \\
 2 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(6 b^2+4 a (b x+1) b+(b x a+a)^2\right)}{(b x+1)^4} \\
 3 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(-24 b^3-18 a (b x+1) b^2-6 (b x a+a)^2 b-(b x a+a)^3\right)}{(b x+1)^5} \\
 4 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(120 b^4+96 a (b x+1) b^3+36 a^2 (b x+1)^2 b^2+8 (b x a+a)^3 b+(b x a+a)^4\right)}{(b x+1)^6} \\
 5 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(-720 b^5-600 a (b x+1) b^4-240 (b x a+a)^2 b^3-60 (b x a+a)^3 b^2-10 (b x a+a)^4 b-(b x a+a)^5\right)}{(b x+1)^7} \\
 6 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(5040 b^6+4320 a (b x+1) b^5+1800 (b x a+a)^2 b^4+480 a^3 (b x+1)^3 b^3+90 (b x a+a)^4 b^2+12 (b x a+a)^5 b+(b x a+a)^6\right)}{(b x+1)^8} \\
 7 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(-40320 b^7-35280 a (b x+1) b^6-15120 (b x a+a)^2 b^5-4200 (b x a+a)^3 b^4-840 (b x a+a)^4 b^3-126 (b x a+a)^5 b^2-14 (b x a+a)^6 b-(b x a+a)^7\right)}{(b x+1)^9} \\
 8 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(362880 b^8+322560 a (b x+1) b^7+141120 (b x a+a)^2 b^6+40320 (b x a+a)^3 b^5+8400 a^4 (b x+1)^4 b^4+1344 (b x a+a)^5 b^3+168 (b x a+a)^6 b^2+16 (b x a+a)^7 b+(b x a+a)^8\right)}{(b x+1)^{10}} \\
 9 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(-3628800 b^9-3265920 a (b x+1) b^8-1451520 (b x a+a)^2 b^7-423360 (b x a+a)^3 b^6-90720 (b x a+a)^4 b^5-15120 (b x a+a)^5 b^4-2016 (b x a+a)^6 b^3-216 (b x a+a)^7 b^2-18 (b x a+a)^8 b-(b x a+a)^9\right)}{(b x+1)^{11}} \\
 10 & \frac{e^{-a x} \left(39916800 b^{10}+36288000 a (b x+1) b^9+16329600 (b x a+a)^2 b^8+4838400 (b x a+a)^3 b^7+1058400 (b x a+a)^4 b^6+181440 a^5 (b x+1)^5 b^5+25200 (b x a+a)^6 b^4+2880 (b x a+a)^7 b^3+270 (b x a+a)^8 b^2+20 (b x a+a)^9 b+(b x a+a)^{10}\right)}{(b x+1)^{12}} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Bad news. The general term contains special functions $a_n=(n+1) (-b)^n \, _1F_1\left(-n;-n-1;\dfrac{a}{b}\right)\quad$ where $F$ is the hypergeometric confluent function

Comment: How do you prove that it reduces to $_1 F_1$ function?

Comment: @Frey https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5BE%5E(-a+x)%2F(b+x+%2B+1)%5E2,+%7Bx,+0,+n%7D%5D